# Add a flextable at a bookmark in the body of a word document from R

Tags: r, flextable, officer

I'm trying to add a flextable at a specific bookmark within the body of a Word document. So far I have found the following options:

- footers_flextable_at_bkm {flextable}
- headers_flextable_at_bkm {flextable}
- body_add_flextable {flextable}

But none of them do exactly what I need.

I tried to write my own code to do it (see below), but it says that the `docx_str` function is not found. (I coped/modified this code from the `headers_flextable_at_bkm` function). Does anyone have a way to do this? Or is it a fuction that could be added to the flextable package?

```
body_flextable_at_bkm <- function(x, bookmark, value){

  stopifnot(inherits(x, "rdocx"), inherits(value, "flextable"))

  str <- docx_str(value, doc = x, align = "center")

  xml_elt <- as_xml_document(x)

  for(doc_obj in x$body){
    if( doc_obj$has_bookmark(bookmark) ){
       doc_obj$cursor_bookmark(bookmark)
       cursor_elt <- doc_obj$get_at_cursor()
       xml_replace(cursor_elt, xml_elt)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should do what you need:

`body_flextable_at_bkm <- function(x, bookmark, value){
  x <- cursor_bookmark(x, bookmark)
  x <- body_add_flextable(x = x, value = value, pos = "on")
  x
}`

Comment: On another note, is there way to automatically calculate and add column sums into the footer of a table?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more digging there is a workaround where you add `set_curser(x, bookmarkID)` before the `body_add_flextable(x, flextable)` command.

For consistaency it would still be nice to have the `body_flextable_at_bkm` as part of the flextable package so it can be used like `headers_flextable_at_bkm` and `footers_flextable_at_bkm` commands.

Edit: the `body_flextable_at_bkm` command should now work with the latest version of the package.